# Exercise about product of graphs in "Conceptual Mathematics"

Tags: category-theory

Please tell me how to solve the following exercise which is in the book "Conceptual Mathematics A first introduction to categories Second Edition".

[image]

How can I show that for any object X of category of graphs the diagram is commutative from the fact that following two diagrams are commutative?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. It is generally recommended to avoid pointing to images with texts and prints from books, and rather retype everything here. This helps this site to become more self-contained, and shows some work. It is also good practice to re-state the problem in your own words (as it's helpful on its own, and may reveals where your lack of understanding is). If you've made any attempt on solving the exercise, it is also kind of you to post it here. Please note you can edit your question anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first observation to make is that given $B_1\overset{a_1}{\leftarrow} C\overset{a_2}{\rightarrow} B_2$, a morphism $A\to C$ (resp. $D\to C$) gives rise to a pair of morphisms $B_1\leftarrow A\rightarrow B_2$ (resp. $B_1\leftarrow D\rightarrow B_2$) by composition with the $a_i$. And by hypothesis, such pairs correspond to morphisms $A\to P$ (resp. $D\to P$). If there are morphisms $f,g:C\to P$ with $$\pi_1\circ f=\pi_1\circ g=a_1$$ and $$\pi_2\circ f=\pi_2\circ g=a_2,$$ then for any $x:A\to C$ it's easy to check that $f\circ x=g\circ x$ by $P$ being a "product with respect to $A$ and $D$", and similarly for any morphism $D\to C$; but then $f=g$ by the (italicized in the text) property of morphisms from $A$ or $D$. So *if* there is a morphism $f:C\to P$ making $\pi_i\circ f=a_i$, it is unique.

How do we prove the *existence* of such a unique $f$? I don't believe the authors have mentioned the really nice thing yet about this category of graphs, where every object is actually a *colimit* of a diagram consisting of $A$s and $D$s; from this, existence is almost immediate. But you can figure it out element-wise by taking an edge $e$ of $C$ to $\langle a_1\circ \tilde{e},a_2\circ \tilde{e}\rangle(e_0)$, where $\tilde{e}$ is the morphism $A\to C$ that picks out the edge $e$, $e_0$ is the unique edge of $A$, and $\langle a_1\circ \tilde{e},a_2\circ \tilde{e}\rangle$ is the unique morphism $A\to P$ corresponding to the pair of morphisms $a_i\circ\tilde{e}:A\to B_i$ (and you do the essentially thing for the graph's vertices and morphisms $D\to C$).

All that's needed is to confirm that this assignment really is a morphism of graphs, which is boring but not too hard. It should be clear that the process I've just described gives us a function from the edges of $C$ to the edges of $P$, and likewise for the vertices. All that's needed to check that it's a morphism of graphs is to check that $$s_P(\langle a_1\circ\tilde{e},a_2\circ\tilde{e}\rangle(e_0))=\langle a_1\circ\widetilde{s_C(e)},a_2\circ\widetilde{s_C(e)}\rangle(d_0)$$ and likewise  $$t_P(\langle a_1\circ\tilde{e},a_2\circ\tilde{e}\rangle(e_0))=\langle a_1\circ\widetilde{t_C(e)},a_2\circ\widetilde{t_C(e)}\rangle(d_0),$$ where $d_0$ and $s_\ldots$ and $t_\ldots$ are the source and target operations on the subscripted graphs. What will make this easier to check is that if $d=s_C(e)$, then, where $x_1,x_2:D\to A$ are the morphisms picking out the source and target vertices respectively in $A$, then $$\widetilde{s_C(e)}=\tilde{d}=\tilde{e}\circ x_1$$ and $$\widetilde{t_C(e)}=\tilde{e}\circ x_2.$$ Moreover $$s_P(\langle a_1\circ\tilde{e},a_2\circ\tilde{e}\rangle(e_0))=\langle a_1\circ\tilde{e},a_2\circ\tilde{e}\rangle\circ x_1(d_0),$$ and similarly with $t$ and $x_2$. With these equalities it should be easy to check.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I understood the uniqueness of morphism $f: C \to P$.

Comment: But I feel difficult to prove the existance of $f$. I think that $<a_1 \circ \tilde{e}, a_2 \circ \tilde{e}>(e)$ is an element of $P$, and that $<a_1 \circ \tilde{e}, a_2 \circ \tilde{e}>$ is a morphism $C \to P$. But you are saying that $<a_1 \circ \tilde{e}, a_2 \circ \tilde{e}>$ is the unique morphism $A \to P$. I am thinking about this difference.

Comment: @konyonyo - That should fix the mistake, and also give you a much stronger lead on confirming the existence of the relevant morphism.

Comment: $f$ is a map such that $e \mapsto <a_1 \circ \tilde{e}, a_2 \circ \tilde{e}>(e_0)$, and $d \mapsto <a_1 \circ \tilde{d}, a_2 \circ \tilde{d}>(d_0)$. It is needed to show that $f$ is a morphism of graphs, i.e. that $s_P(<a_1\circ \tilde{e},a_2\circ\tilde{e}>(e_0))=<a_1\circ\tilde{s_C(e)},a_2\circ\tilde{s_C(e)}>(d_0)$ and similar equation for $t_P$. I assigned $\tilde{s_C(e)}=\tilde{e}\circ x_1$ to the right hand side of the equation. And right hand side of it becomes $<a_1\circ\tilde{e}\circ x_1, a_2\circ\tilde{e}\circ x_1>(d_0)=<a_1\circ\tilde{e},a_2\circ\tilde{e}>\circ x_1(d_0)$.

Comment: Then $<a_1\circ\tilde{e},a_2\circ\tilde{e}>\circ x_1(d_0)$ is equal to $s_P(<a_1\circ\tilde{e},a_2\circ\tilde{e}>(e_0))$.

Comment: The above is my current understanding. Thank you for helping me thinking.

Comment: That is correct.